Factoring Polynomials over $\mathbb R$ using SageMath
I'm new to Sage and computer algebra systems in general, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to factor polynomials over $\mathbb R$ where the factorization includes radicals instead of decimal approximations.
For example, if I want to factor $x^2 - 2$ over $\mathbb R$, I can use
R.<x> = RR[]

factor(x^2 - 2)

which returns
(x - 1.41421356237310) * (x + 1.41421356237310)

But if I use
solve(x^2 - 2 == 0, x)

it returns the roots in a radical form:
[x == -sqrt(2), x == sqrt(2)]

So I would think there should be a way to have Sage return the factorization as $(x - \sqrt 2)(x + \sqrt2)$.
It's probably not too difficult to write a function that does this, using the roots obtained from
solve()

but I would like to know if it's already built into Sage.

Do you know about the quadratic, cubic, and quartic formulas?As well as the unsolvability of the quintic. Those should answer some of your questions (since this procedure is not in general possible).

There's a "sort-of" answer here which suggestions using the radical_expression() function.

@Malady Yes, I do. I'm only interested in the cases where Sage provides exact forms using solve(), which it does for cubics and quartics.

@Mathmo123 Thanks for the link! I did see this, but for some reason I can't get radical_expression() to work. I was hoping there was there was an easier way that my students who don't have any programming experience would still be able to understand.
